# Is Nginx okay for my ecommerce portal

Tags: php, nginx, vps

First of all i am not a system administer, but need help. I am about to set up my webserver on a linux VPS hosting for an ecommerce portal with expected traffic of 10000 concurrent hits.
I need to know that is NGINX alone okay for all my needs. My application would be in dynamic contents like php. On the other hand i want the website to load speed, may be as i searched google, i found a server caching will be okay. Please let me know how to do that. Will i be able to install all applications or i need a professional help ? I am in tight budget.

Thank you!

Comment: I am also considering for a dedicated server now from,serverbeach.com, with 1Gb ram, 500GB HDD & 1 TB bandwidth. Thanks for replying.

Comment: The scripts are in PHP with MVC framework. Need your suggestion for the ideal configuration.

NGINX is good for Static content but what about the dynamic content ? How to deal with it ?

What is your opinion on installing Tornado for Dynamic requests ? And static requests like images, CSS etc should be handled by NGINX, and all dynamic PHP etc requests should be handled through Tornado.

What you say ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10k concurrent sessions on a VPS sounds a bit risky. I would rent a dedicated server for this.

Wether you can use nginx solely alone depends on your software. Some depends on apache modules (like htaccess support), where they have to use nginx in front and apache as a backend.

I use nginx+PFP-FPM+APC with great success, but as I said - it won't suit everyone.

Perhaps you should install VMWare Workstation and try this out first.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx is designed to handle large amounts of traffic, and should be able to do everything you need. What are the specs of your VPS though, 10K concurrent hits seems like a lot to expect it to be capable of.

nginx can run php, not quite as simple as setting up mod_php etc., in apache, but it is fairly [well documented](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxConfiguration#PHP_via_FastCGI). It can also [cache](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule) this.

There's a lot of documentation and examples out there for nginx now, if you have some prior experience with linux and/or web servers it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

The major feature of Nginx along with other light-weighted HTTP Servers ([LightHTTPD](http://www.lighttpd.net/), [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/)) is the use of Event Loop which uses single thread with one or more than one worker processes for handling all connections instead of one thread per connection as done by Apache HTTPD.

Nginx is especially effective when the number of concurrent users are high. But if you provide quite minimum hardware and expect high availability then, its not gonna happen.

You can write a simple script and test that script against Apache HTTPD and Nginx using [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) and compare the stats